# Error when execute Dynamic Pivot Table MySQL

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I have a table that I want to create a dynamic pivot table.

```
> NAMA_LOKASI| NAMA_MODEL | JUMLAH 
    IT       | Core_2_Duo | 20 
    IT       |Core_i3_2100| 5 
    HRD      | Core_2_Duo | 10 
    HRD      |Core_i3_2100| 10 
    ....
```

I want to make my table like this :

```
>   NAMA_LOKASI| Core_2_Duo | Core_i3_2100 | ....
         IT    |     20     |      5       | ......
         HRD   |     10     |      10      | ......

         ....
```

this is my query

```
    SET @sql_dinamis = (
    select 
        GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT
            CONCAT ('SUM (IF(NAMA_MODEL = '
            ,NAMA_MODEL
            ,',JUMLAH,0)) AS '
            , NAMA_MODEL
            )
        )
        from v_barang2
    );

   SET @SQL = CONCAT('SELECT nama_lokasi, ', 
              @sql_dinamis, ' 
           FROM v_barang2 

           GROUP BY nama_lokasi WITH ROLLUP'
       );


PREPARE TEST FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE TEST;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE TEST;
```

but when I execute my query, it show this dialog box

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM v_barang2 
>              GROUP BY nama_lokasi WITH ROLLUP' at line 2

I use phpMyAdmin version 4.8.4. Please help for a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really easy to check the validity of your sql statement - just put a select in after the 2 set statements and then copy and paste the result and run it. In this case you will find 1 definite error and 1 possible error. The definite error is cause by a space between sum and (, the possible error will occur if nama_model is a number - you cannot use an alias staring with or solely consisting of a number.

```
SET @sql_dinamis = (
    select 
        GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT
            CONCAT ('SUM(IF(NAMA_MODEL = '
            ,NAMA_MODEL
            ,',JUMLAH,0)) AS '
            , char(39),nama_model,char(39)
            )
        )
        from v_barang2
    );

   SET @SQL = CONCAT('SELECT nama_lokasi, ', 
              @sql_dinamis, ' 
           FROM v_barang2 

           GROUP BY nama_lokasi WITH ROLLUP'
       );


   SET @SQL = CONCAT('SELECT nama_lokasi, ', 
              @sql_dinamis, ' 
           FROM v_barang2 

           GROUP BY nama_lokasi WITH ROLLUP'
       );
```

produces this

```
SELECT nama_lokasi, SUM(IF(NAMA_MODEL = 1,JUMLAH,0)) AS '1',
SUM(IF(NAMA_MODEL = 2,JUMLAH,0)) AS '2' 
FROM v_barang2 
GROUP BY nama_lokasi WITH ROLLUP
```

Which when run against this

```
drop table if exists v_barang2;          
Create table v_barang2(nama_lokasi int , nama_model int, jumlah int);
insert into v_barang2 values(1,1,1),(1,2,1),(2,1,1);
```

produces

```
+-------------+------+------+
| nama_lokasi | 1    | 2    |
+-------------+------+------+
|           1 |    1 |    1 |
|           2 |    1 |    0 |
|        NULL |    2 |    1 |
+-------------+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Please note it's better that you provide sample data when posting a question, rather than me guessing what's appropriate from a lump of non working code.

Comment: Thanks, it is because of I did not put (" ") after NAMA_MODEL at @sql_dinamis. 
And I also delete the space between SUM and ( and it is works.
Thankyou for your answer